# ObjectOutputStream won't save my arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, objectoutputstream

I have this arrayList in my UserArchive class, and a saveFile() method in my MainWindow class.
My problem is that every time I close the program all that shows in src/customerlist.txt is:
 ¨ÌsrUserArchiveYï≈ùÅ—ÀDLlisttLjava/util/ArrayList;xpsrjava.util.ArrayListxÅ“ô«aùIsizexpw
x.

Heres my code: Can anyone spot any problems?

```
public class UserArchive implements Serializable {
ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

public void regCustomer(User u) {
    list.add(u);
}

    public String toString() {
    sorter();
    String users = "";
    Iterator<User> iterator = list.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        users += iterator.next().toString() + "\n";
    }
    return users;
}
```

MainWindow class:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
private SaleWindow sW;
private UserArchive userA;
int customerID = 0;
```

////

```
    public void saveFile() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(
                "src/customerlist.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream utfil = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
        utfil.writeObject(userA);
        utfil.close();
    } catch (NotSerializableException nse) {
        JOptionPane
                .showMessageDialog(this, "Objektet er ikke serialisert!");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        JOptionPane
                .showMessageDialog(this, "Problem med utskrift til fil!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes because ObjectOutputStream serializes objects in binary form. If you want serialize in some ASCII form try a JSON Serializer for example [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

Comment: So there is no way i could save it using ObjectOutputStream? That´s what I´ve always done before. This is a school project and we are suppose to use ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: You can save it and load it with ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream but not in textual form, but in binary which will work just you loose the ability to view/edit it as a text file. If you want to store it in textual form you need to use a FileWriter/FileReader and write your own serialization mechanism.

Comment: I dont think I need to view/edit it as a text file. All I need is to save it so i can print it out to the screen again when I open the program after closing it.

Comment: Then there aren't any problems, but instead of the .txt extension use a .bin or something else to show it's a binary and use ObjectInputStream to load it back.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Javas serialization mechanismn. You're not writing the String **content** but the String **objects** (and the sourrounding list) in their binary form.

ObjectOutputStream is the wrong choice if all you want to do is write a plain text file. Take a closer look at java.io.FileWriter or java.io.PrintWriter.